# ¿como unir varios archivos excel en un dataframe?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Tengo varios archivos excel con datos del mismo tipo.
Son los resultados de un analisis con un dataframe y los resultados de cada dia estan en un archivo excel distinto, por lo que tienen las mismas columnas, tipos etc.
Queria ver como podia hacer para automaticamente leer todos los archivos excel de la carpeta y juntarlos en un excel único con todos los datos en la misma hoja.
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con la librería **openpixl** que permite leer y escribir archivos excel. (Nota: ten en cuenta que trabaja con formato excel 2010)
Si estás en windows, la puedes instalar con el comando pip:

```
pip install openpyxl
```

Aquí tienes un documento con ejemplos y tutoriales [CLICK AQUÍ](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)